# Is it possible to click and drag an image with Sikuli until the image is no longer present?

Tags: python, sikuli

So using the dragDrop feature of Sikuli I've managed to click and image and drag it to x,y coordinates.

If multiple of the same images are present in succession, is it possible to click an image and then drag the mouse vertically to a point where the image is no longer present?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
while exists("image.png"):
     # do something with the image
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can drag your images to the same point wherever they are located:

```
 x = find (Point picture)

 for y in findAll (image to drag):

        dragDrop (y,x)
```